# ASP.NET Prevent FormView from switching templates when data is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I have a FormView and when user is on InsertTemplate, I want the FormView to stay on the InsertTemplate after user clicked the Insert button if the data inside the InsertTemplate is not valid.

I have tried to use many events in FormView but none of them worked.
The closest event I can guess is FormView_ItemInserting()

```
protected void OfferDataFormView_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid == false)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't even get triggered after the Insert button was clicked. So I cannot stop the FV changing its template from InsertTemplate to EditTemplate.

Comment: Is the ASP.NET WebForm really dying technology? Not even one person replies.....

Comment: One day has passed, yet no one responses and only got viewed 7 times.... I can see that people are losing interest in old ASP.NET WebForms.... can anyone at least comments my question to show your support? thx

Comment: Do you have any field validator controls on the form? If you do and thus the state of the bound model is IsValue=false, the insert command won't fire hence the ItemInserting event is not firing. Did you check Page.IsValid on your button click event?